# Angular JS and Web API Architecture

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have to prepare an architecture with following technologies:

1. Angular JS 1.5
2. MVC 5.0/Web API.
3. EF 6.0

Is it a good option to have a single web project which has angular JS and Web API. 
We need to expose web api's to other third party vendors. So, we are thinking to create a separate web api project as a separate project. Need your inputs.

Thanks,
Dhannajay

Comment: Input: based on your description, we have nothing to say.

Comment: look at here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Architecture-real-world-8ac333a2/view/SourceCode#content

Answer (score 0):

you can do this (like [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Architecture-real-world-8ac333a2/sourcecode?fileId=141308&pathId=833488812))

- API: your api front end
- Core: business logic/EF
- MVC: html/mvc/angularjs
- DTO: classes/models

Answer (score 0):

You can have a lot of options to define the architecture, but to answer your questions, I think is better have separate projects in this case for the following reasons:

- You can change the front-end without touch any in the api system (web api) and viceversa
- You can scale both sites or only one, maybe, the front-end goes well, but you need more power in the web api, go ahead and scale only the api.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Is there any sample available around this having. And, will there be any disadvantages with this approach.